# Error in installation of TideSDK

Tags: javascript, native, tidesdk

Has this happened to anyone? How to solve?

*Couldn't load file:/home/familia/.tidesdk/TideSDK/runtime/1.3.1-beta/libtide.so, error: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

Comment: You might want to post this on http://superuser.com/. It is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You need install the libjpeg with terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

This link have all the librarys required 
https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Tidesdk-build-ubuntu-12.04